# How do I find the first and last day of next month?

Tags: r, date

If I have a given date, how do I find the first and last days of the next month?

For example,

```
today <- as.Date("2009-04-04")
```

I want to find

```
# first date in next month
"2009-05-01"  

# last date in next month
"2009-05-31"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with base R:

```
today <- as.Date("2009-04-04")

first <- function(x) {
  x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
  x$mon[] <- x$mon + 1
  x$mday[] <- 1
  x$isdst[] <- -1L
  as.Date(x)
}

first(today)
#[1] "2009-05-01"

first(first(today)) - 1
#[1] "2009-05-31"
```

Answer (score 4):

`lubridate` has some useful tools for this purpose.

```
library(lubridate)

today <- ymd("2009-04-12")

# First day of next month
first <- ceiling_date(today, unit = "month")
# Last day of next month
last <- ceiling_date(first, unit= "month") -1


first
#"2009-05-01"

last
#"2009-05-31"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions.  We use `today` from the question to test.  In both cases the input may be a `Date` class vector.

**1) Base R**   Define function `fom` to give the first of the month of its `Date` 
argument.  Using that we can get the date of the first and last of the next month as follows.  We use the facts that 31 and 62 days after the first of the month is necessarily a date in the next month and month after the next month.

```
fom <- function(x) as.Date(cut(x, "month"))

fom(fom(today) + 31)
## [1] "2009-05-01"

fom(fom(today) + 62) - 1
## [1] "2009-05-31"
```

**2) yearmon**  `yearmon` class objects internally represent a year and month as the year plus 0 for January, 1/12 for Febrary, 2/12 for March and so on. Using `as.Date.yearmon` the `frac` argument specifies the fraction of the way through the month to output.  The default is `frac = 0` and results in the first of the month being output and `frac = 1` means the end of the month.

```
library(zoo)

as.Date(as.yearmon(today) + 1/12)
## [1] "2009-05-01"

as.Date(as.yearmon(today) + 1/12, frac = 1)
## [1] "2009-05-31"
```